# Unique solution of an integral equation in $L^1[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, integral-equations

Let $h\in L^1[0,1]$. Prove that there is a unique solution (almost everywhere) of the following integral equation:
$$f(x)=h(x)+\frac{1}{2}\int_0^x\log(1+f(y)^2)dy$$
The idea is to use the fixed-point theorem for Banach spaces.
So let's consider the map:
$$T:L^1[0,1]\to L^1[0,1],f(x)\mapsto h(x)+\frac{1}{2}\int_0^x\log(1+f(y)^2)dy$$
I want to prove that this is a contraction map.
So i want to find a constant $C<1$ such that $||T(f)-T(g)||_1\leq C||f-g||_1$.
$$||T(f)-T(g)||_1=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1|\int_0^x\log(1+f(y)^2)-\log(1+g(y)^2)dy|dx$$
Taking the absolute value under the integral and then changing the order of integration:
$$||T(f)-T(g)||_1\leq \frac{1}{2}\int_0^1\int_0^x|\log(1+f(y)^2)-\log(1+g(y)^2)|dydx$$
So $$||T(f)-T(g)||\leq \frac{1}{2}\int_0^1(1-y)|\log(1+f(y)^2)-\log(1+g(y)^2)|dy$$
But from here i'm not able to find the exstimation.

Comment: I think you've made a mistake with integrating. I don't see how you got rid of your $dx$ bit. Looks like a valiant effort so far. You might also try to show that the sequence $T^n(f)$ is Cauchy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First idea: Use the mean value theorem on $g (x)= \ln (1 + x^2) $ to get $$g (x)-g (y) = \frac {2\xi}{1+\xi^2} (x-y) $$ and estimate the fraction.

Comment: first idea, and also a good idea. Thank you.